# run batch file in all subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

ok so i have a simple batch file someone created for me to basically count all files in current folder and then create 3 folders like so

Photos\2017_11_01\3
Photos\2017_11_01\10
Photos\2017_11_01\30

code is as follows

```
@echo off
:: get total number of files
for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.jpg ^| find /v /c ""') do set /A total=%%A

:: create subfolders and calculate skip
for %%A in (3 10 30) Do (
  mkdir "%%A"
  if %%A neq 30 (
    Set /A "skip%%A=total/25/%%A
  ) Else (
    Set /A "skip%%A=total/%%A
  )
)

set Counter=0
for %%f in (*.jpg) do call :p "%%f"
goto :EOF

:p
set /a "Counter+=1,X=Counter%%skip3,Y=Counter%%skip10,Z=Counter%%skip30"
if %X%==0 copy %1 "3"
if %Y%==0 copy %1 "10"
if %Z%==0 copy %1 "30"
goto :eof
```

Is copies files from the current folder into the newly created folders and has worked like a charm since MAY this year. Trouble is its very time consuming and have to do this on a daily basis or weekly. However i havent done it for 2 months so no i have nearly 60 folders to go through which would take me all day.

My Question 
Can this be modified so that i can run the batch file in the "Photos" folder and have it run in each subfolder recursively.

I don't want to automate it daily for a couple of reasons. so being able to run the batch file in multiple subfolder at once would be a massive improvement.

Comment: `recursively` means: run it in *every* folder below the root folder (including sub-sub-folders, sub-sub-sub-folders etc.,) Is that what you want? Or just every folder in the root folder (just one step deep) ?

Comment: Hi yes sorry.  So i would like to place the batch file in the "Photos" root folder and have it run in every folder one step deep ("2017_11_01", "2017_11_02" etc ) . The script takes about 2 mins to run so ideally one folder at a time (im guessing that how it would work anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using your working script as is and build a wrapper:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (20*) do (
  echo processing %%a
  pushd "%%a"
  call "%~dp0yourcurrentscript.bat"
  popd
)
```

Comment: Cool i'll give it a go and let you know the results

Comment: OK, so i tried that. i edited "yourcurrentscript.bat" with my existing script "folder_sort.bat" Then placed both the root folder and ran. This is what i get.C:\Users\John\Pictures\IPTimelapse\test>root_sort.bat
processing 2017_11_06
'folder_sort.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
processing 2017_11_07
'folder_sort.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: The above works if "folder_sort.bat" is present in each subfolder.

Comment: edited to look for `folder_sort.bat` in the same folder as `root_sort.bat`

Comment: Added "~" after Call - call "%~dp0yourcurrentscript.bat"

Comment: Thanks for you help. Made life a little easier. Just need to tweak the original script again :) cheers